# Cache size of Firefox?

Tags: firefox

How do I go about to increase the cache size of Firefox? Firefox crashes occasionally when I have four windows open with multiple tabs.

Answer (score 2):

In the address bar type: `about:config`, when the warning message appears, click on "I'll be careful, I promise!". Look for the following entry:

```
browser.cache.disk.capacity
```

Double-click to edit., and change the value

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open Firefox preferences window under 'Edit'->'preferences'.

In the preference window that opens up, select the Advanced tab and then the Network tab. Your cache management settings will be under 'Cached Web Content'.

Check the 'overide automatic cache management' and select your preferred cache size.

See screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Preferences->Advanced->Network->Cashed Web Content`. Tick to override automatic cashe management and set something in there.